# Localization for Label StringFormat in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.forms, localization, label, string-formatting

In xamarin forms I can localize the text in a label like:
`<Label Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.Text}"/>`

With a namespace for the resources:
`<ContentView ...
xmlns:resources="clr-namespace:ProjectName.Resources;assembly=ProjectName">`

I can also bind some value and add a string format to the label:
`<Label  Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat='The value is: {0}' }"/>`

The problem is that the text **The value is:** is not localized.

Who can I do both, bind a value and localize the StringFormat?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer at [Localizing XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-ca/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?tabs=vswin#localizing-xaml)

I had to add the text **The value is: {0}** to the resource file.
I needed to add an IMarkupExtension for the translation. I added the class to the same namespace as the resource file.

```
[ContentProperty("Text")]
public class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    private readonly CultureInfo _ci;

    static readonly Lazy<ResourceManager> ResMgr = new Lazy<ResourceManager>(
        () => new ResourceManager(typeof(AppResources).FullName, typeof(TranslateExtension).GetTypeInfo().Assembly));

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public TranslateExtension()
    {
        if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS || Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android)
        {
            _ci = DependencyService.Get<ILocalize>().GetCurrentCultureInfo();
        }
    }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Text == null)
            return string.Empty;

        return ResMgr.Value.GetString(Text, _ci) ?? Text;
    }
}
```

and use it like:

`<Label Text="{Binding Value, StringFormat={resources:Translate LabelTextTheValueIs}}" />`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to just use the normal localized resources line without any extension, like so:

```
Text="{Binding WireValue, StringFormat={x:Static resources:AppResources.PaymentDetailsLine3}}"
```

Where PaymentDetailsLine3 is in my AppResources.resx as:

```
   <data
  name="PaymentDetailsLine3"
  xml:space="preserve">
  <value>PaymentDetailsLine3 {0}</value>
```