# Xamarin Forms - Reference a resource within declaration of a StringFormat

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, prism

Im trying to make a reference to a .resx varaiable inside the declaration of a string format. The .resx file just contains a english and a danish variation of the word, that just needs to stand in front of the binded variable.

***Xaml***

```
<Label Text="{Binding PracticeNo, StringFormat={Resources:Translate Practice_Number}': {0}'}"/>
```

I want the outcome to be like this:

*English:*
Practice number: 123

*Dansih:*
Praksisnummer: 123

I have figured out a workaround, just using a stacklayout with orientation horizontal, but i was just curious if it was possible to do it with af Stringformat?

Comment: This is a really interesting question - are you allowed to localize the string format in xamarin forms xaml (or just static text, that is, you'd have to do the localization in the view model)? EDIT: it's also already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63569998/5758420

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have figured out a workaround, just using a stacklayout with orientation horizontal, but i was just curious if it was possible to do it with af Stringformat?

You can use Spans to combine data and text.

```
<Label>
        <Label.FormattedText>
            <FormattedString>
                <Span Text="{x:Static resources:AppResources.Practice_Number}" />
                <Span Text=" :" />
                <Span Text="{Binding PracticeNo}" />
            </FormattedString>
        </Label.FormattedText>
    </Label>
```

[image]